# Signup on a Game by using other's email addresses

Tags: account-security

What if someone signs up on a game by using your email address without your permission? What if someone signs up using your email address illegally?

I'm not talking about signing in and stealing credentials. Someone just signs up for a new account.

What they can do next? Is this something to be afraid of?

Comment: In what way is this illegal?

Comment: It is illegal cause the account owner did not give the permission to use his email for signup.

Comment: And is that illegal? Just because you don't like it doesn't make it illegal ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sign up for a game or a website, you're typically required to confirm your e-mail address by, for example, clicking on a link with a random number that has been sent to your mailbox. Somebody who only knows your address but doesn't have access to your mailbox won't be able to do that, so the registration will fail.

If no such protection exists, then an attacker could try to impersonate you in the game. How successful this will depend on the exact system. Is the e-mail address shown to other users? Then they could think it's your account. An attacker could try to use this, for example, to get information from people who trust you or damage your reputation. Is the address only used internally? Then the attacker could attempt to convince the game staff that the account is yours -- again, the possible damage is going to depend on the exact case.

Comment: @NoobHunter Ja1024 explains how one could damage reputation.

Comment: @schroeder Actually I found this bug on a game with Bug Bounty Program. The bug is allowing me to Signup without confirmation but abviously the new accounts are fully empty. So is it impactful/valid bug or not? and in which severity is it?

Comment: @NoobHunter you are the tester - you need to sort out the impact ... we will ***not*** do your bug bounties for you ...

Comment: @schroeder I'm here to sort out the impact, and the explaination of Ja1024 really helped me and cleared my concept so I asked the main Impact, and I think this community made for it. So we can help each other.